# Conditional table, how to fill it

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, contingency-tables

I found this question and since I'm learning probability I'm not sure how to go about it:

```
Of a company’s employees, 30% are 
women and 6% are married women. 
Suppose an employee is selected at 
random. If the employee selected is a 
woman, what is the probability that she is 
married?
```

I have done it like this:

```
    W       W'

M  0.018

M' 0.282   
  p(W)=0.3  p(W')0.7

p(W')=1-p(W)=1-0.3=0.7
p(M and W)=p(W)p(M|W)=0.3x0.06=0.018
p(W and M')=p(W)-p(M and W')= 0.3-0.018=0.282
```

Well that's where I'm at, how do I go about it next? Can I get this numbers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       Wom   Man
Mar     x     y
Sing    w     z
```

You are mixing up the concepts of joint and conditional probability.

**Problem:**

$x = P(M,W) = 0.06$

$x+w = P(W) = 0.3$

$P(M|W) = ?$

**Solution:**

$P(M|W) = P(M,W) / P(W) $

Comment: So is not given that they are woman are married, is and, ok ok, but how can I fill the missing info, like p(Man and Mar), or with this is not possible?

Comment: $P(Man) = y+z = 1-(x+w) = 0.7$ but you cannot calculate the exact values of $y$ and $z$ with the information given in the problem.